# What does INT64 and DECIMAL(18,6) means in Parquet file format?

Tags: java, parquet

I run [parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) with meta argument on one of my Parquet files:

```
optional int64 my_column (DECIMAL(18,6))
```

What does this means? The [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/#sql-types-to-parquet-logical-types) defines two different types: `INT_64` and `DECIMAL`. Why [parquet-tools](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) outputs me both of them? What result type is it?